# "Parameters passed by value" CLRS Algorithms

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pointers, parameter-passing

What do the authors mean by the statement "the data representing the object is copied but the object's attributes are not", an someone give me an example of how this works in practice, perhaps in python or java or C?

---

The following is an excerpt from the first chapter of CLRS algorithms.

"We pass parameters to a procedure by value: the called procedure receives its own copy of the parameters, and if it assigns a value to a parameter, the change is not seen by the calling procedure. When objects are passed, the pointer to the data representing the object is copied, but the object’s attributes are not. For example, if x is a parameter of a called procedure, the assignment x = y within the called procedure is not visible to the calling procedure. The assignment x.f =3, however, is visible. Similarly, arrays are passed by pointer, so that a pointer to the array is passed, rather than the entire array, and changes to individual array elements are visible to the calling procedure"

Thank you in advance for helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of pretty much all modern imperative programming languages which have immutable primitives and mutable objects, such as Java, Python, Javascript, and so on. I'll use Javascript for examples, but if you don't know Javascript hopefully the code is simple enough that you understand the explanation anyway.

---

Consider the following code which declares a variable and calls a function:

```js
function foo(x) {
    x = 5;
}

var y = 2;
foo(y);
console.log(y); // outputs number 2
```

The variable `x` within the function gets its value from `y`, but is a different variable stored in a different place in memory. So when the function assigns the number 5 to `x`, the number 5 is **not** also assigned to `y`; the change in `x` is not "visible" outside the function.

Now consider this code, which is essentially the same, just with an object instead of a number:

```js
function bar(x) {
    x = { a: 3, b: 4 };
}

var y = { a: 1, b: 2 };
bar(y);
console.log(y); // outputs { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Again, `x` gets its value from `y` (which is a reference to the object), but assigning a new reference to `x` doesn't change which reference `y` holds because they are stored in different memory locations.

Now the final example:

```js
function baz(x) {
    x.a = 3;
    x.b = 4;
}

var y = { a: 1, b: 2 };
baz(y);
console.log(y); // outputs { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

This time the function `baz` *does* change the result, because `y` holds a reference to the object, and when the function is called, `x` holds a reference to the same object (not a copy of the object), so the assignments to its properties *are* "visible" outside of the function.

---

If all of this seems straightforward to you, then you can ignore the paragraph; it is simply explaining that the language they use in the book has these behaviours. The purpose of the paragraph is to clarify the semantics of their language, because not all functions in all languages do behave in these ways.

In C++ for example, it is possible to write `foo` and `bar` in such a way that they *would* change the value of y "from a distance". Or, in a functional programming language where objects are immutable, `baz` *wouldn't* change the object `y`, it would instead create new objects with different properties, which wouldn't be visible outside the function.

So this paragraph in their book is a useful clarification for readers who might be more familiar with these other semantics for function parameters.